Question revival of the week
I occasionally peruse some of the older questions on the site and often find some really insightful questions that, for whatever reason, didn't get the attention they deserve at the time they were originally asked.  If I know the answer, I add it, and if I don't, I often at least try to edit it to bump it up to the front page.  I notice some others on the site have also done this on occasion.  I think that's great and I encourage more of us to do that.
I would like to propose something a bit more formal to get some really great past questions their well-deserved great answers.  Please post below your suggestion for a question revival of the week (one question per post).  I need your help in finding some great revival candidates!
In about a week, I'll add a bounty (I'll start it off at +50, but may bump it up later).  Those of us who feel qualified enough should make the effort to either improve the question, improve the existing answers, or add your own answers.  I'll award the bounty to whichever answer gets the most new up-votes.
Feel free to suggest your own questions or questions you already know the answer to but feel it would take too much of your time to write a proper answer that is normally not likely to get that much attention.  Per the revival and necromancer badge rules, I only ask that the question be either at least 60 days old or at least 30 days old with no answer scoring 2 or more.
If this works, at the same time, I'll start a new meta post for the next question revival of the week.  Eventually perhaps others can occasionally pitch in the bounty, but I don't mind doing it for a while.
Update: So far 4 people seem to have liked this proposal in theory, but no one has suggested any questions, so I'll leave this question open until someone comes along and suggests a question.

Nice suggestion. Perhaps take the open question with the highest # of votes and work down the list? On another note, I more concerned about the pace of questions. The new questions/day is not impressive.

Yeah, that's easy, and I've done that somewhat, but I was really hoping for some help identifying questions which appear to have been answered but which actually have relatively poor answers.  I'm also worried about new questions/day, particularly if you exclude all the off-topic questions we're getting.
